# Least privileges required to get ddl of an sybase database

Tags: permissions, sap-ase

I have an **Sybase** database and a user that has all privileges to access that database. Now I want to create a new user who can only get the DDL of all objects like user tables,views,procedures,functions etc in database and can only read the data. What are the **least privileges or roles** that are needed to be granted to the new user? I don't want to perform any kind of alter, update or delete on that database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be the 'dbo' database user for the database you want to reverse-engineer. The easiest way to achieved this is by granting sa_role & sso_role to the login that you're using to connect to the ASE server.

Comment: Thank you sir but if I grant **sa_role** to 'user2' then he will be able to access database too and can perform any operation on it. I don't want to grant any kind of alter, delete, insert permission to 'user2', i.e., I want to revoke all the permissions from 'user2' except select permission and ddl get permission.

Comment: If you only want to read the catalog contents, you do not need to give any priviliges. Apart from the security-related columns, those tables are readable.